# A Lemma in Serre's Arithmetic

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, abelian-groups, exact-sequence

In Serre's A Course in Arithmetic, he writes the following lemma:

Lemma: Let $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow E\rightarrow B\rightarrow 0$ be an exact sequence of commutative groups with $A$ and $B$ finite with orders $a$ and $b$ prime to each other. Let $B'$ be the set of $x\in E$ such that $bx=0$. The group $E$ is the direct sum of $A$ and $B'$.

Then in the proof, he says "since $bB'=0$, we have $bE\subset A$". I don't quite follow where this statement comes from. Can someone offer a hint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $p:E\rightarrow B$ the projection. Remark that for every $x\in E$, whe have $p(bx)=0$ since the order of $B$ is $B$. This  implies that $bx\in A$ since the sequence is exact, we deduce that a $abx =0$.

We have $1=ua+vb$ implies that for every $x\in E$, $x=uax+vbx$. We have $vbx=bvx\in A$, and $b(uax)=u(abx)=0$ im plies that $uax\in B'$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT.** Use exactness of the sequence.

Comment: Any more details?

Comment: @Christina Use exactness and the relative co-prime-ness of the groups. Does that get you there?

Comment: Yes! Thank you!

Comment: No problem! Note that this is essentially the group version of $0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$, with maps $f,g$, that $B= \im f \oplus \ker g$ for vector spaces. You can also view this proof: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600271/showing-an-exact-sequence-of-groups-is-split where the sequence *fully* splits because of the prime-ness of the group orders. But here this is not necessarily so - we just get the 'kernel' piece.

Comment: I can now see why $bE\subset A$ is true. But I am still kind of confused about how $bB'=0$ implies $bE\subset A$.

Comment: @Christina Did you use relative co-primeness and the order of the groups?

Comment: Yes, but I don't see the necessity of using $bB'=0$.